# Paperclip on S3 - retrieve deleted files?

Tags: amazon-s3, paperclip

I just made a massive cock-up in my rails app. I deleted half the users from the database on my dev site, thinking this would have no effect on the live site db, which seems to have led to the user avatars being removed on the live site!

I don't know much about paperclip or S3 but I'm begging for help if anyone knows if it is possible to get them back?

Does S3 have backups? Have the images really been deleted or just somehow detached from their associated user object?

I'm using paperclip in my user model file like so:

```
# paperclip avatars on S3
has_attached_file :avatar, {
                  :styles => { :medium => "200x200", :small => "100x100#", :thumb => "64x64#" },
                  :default_url => "/assets/profiles/avatar_default_200x200.png",
                  :path => "/avatars/:style/:id/:filename"
}.merge(PAPERCLIP_STORAGE_OPTIONS)

validates_attachment_size :avatar, :less_than => 2.megabytes,
                        :unless => Proc.new {|m| m[:image].nil?}
validates_attachment_content_type :avater, :content_type=>['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif'],
                                :unless => Proc.new {|m| m[:image].nil?}
```

Thanks for any information!

Comment: Did you add VERSIONING to S3 buckets? You can add VERSIONING to S3 buckets. This will cause S3 to keep versions of an object even after deletion. Full documentation: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Versioning.html

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't have it; I do now though. Post that as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't enabled versioning in S3, I guess you're out of luck.

In order to keep track of deleted objects from s3 you can add versioning to S3 buckets. This will cause S3 to keep versions of an object even after deletion.

Details can be found [here](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Versioning.html).

Comment: Is it possible to retrieve a deleted file over AWS Console? Can't find a way to do that.